# How to parse Bank information into particular format, plus java questions

Tags: java, class, parsing, tostring

Doing a java assignment in CSE 205 at ASU, and I'm having a hard time understanding parsing. I've looked through our online textbook, and parsing rarely comes up and it's never given a full explanation. I've looked through the java api documentation a few times and I never understand what it's saying, so I hope someone isn't too frustrated as to explain how to do it.

The class is:

BankParser

The BankParser class is a utility class that will be used to create bank objects from a string. The BankParser class cannot be instantiated. It has the following method:

public static Bank bankParser(String lineToParse)

The bankParser method's argument will be a string in the following format:

bankName/bankID/city,state

A real example of this string would be:

Bank Arizona/10001/Phoenix,AZ

The bankParser method will parse this string, pull out the information, create a new bank object, set the attributes of the object, and return it.

So far this is my setup:

```
public class BankParser {

public static Bank bankParser(String lineToParse) {

}

}
```

Also, in my Bank class I have this toString method:

```
    public String toString() {
    String printInfo = ("\nBank name:\t" + bankName + "\nBank ID:\t" + bankID +     "\nBank address:\t" + bankAddress + "\n");
    return printInfo;
```

It gives me 2 markers in eclipse: that this overrides java.lang.Object.toString, and that the return type is missing. What does this all mean?? The return type is String, I don't see what the problem is with that, but the override I'm clueless

EDIT; This is what I've come up with for bankParser

```
    public static Bank bankParser(String lineToParse) {
    String[] returnValue = lineToParse.split("/");
    Bank temp = new Bank();
    temp.setbankName(returnValue[0]);
    temp.setbankID(returnValue[1]);
    temp.setbankAddress = (returnValue[2]); //this one won't work, see below
       return temp;
}

}
```

And THESE are the methods in Bank and Address that apply to bankParser

```
    public void setBankName(String bank1) {
    bankName = bank1;
}

public void setBankID(String bankID1) {
    bankID = bankID1;
}

public void setBankAddress(String city, String state) {
    bankAddress.setCity(city);
    bankAddress.setState(state);
}
```

In Address.java:

```
    public void setCity(String city1) {
    city = city1;
}

public void setState(String state1) {
    state = state1;
}
```

Comment: OK, so you know that you need two Strings now for the address. After seeing how to split your String, surely you can figure out how to split the last String some more. I know you can figure this one out!

Comment: I got it! Thanks so much, is there a way for me to "close" this thread or mark as answered? I clicked the checkmark on yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bankParser method is empty. It needs to return a Bank object, and Java will complain until you do this.  You could always have it return null for now til, make it at least a compilable stub you figure this out:

```
public static Bank bankParser(String lineToParse) {
   Bank returnValue = null;
   // TODO: create a Bank object, assign to returnValue
   return returnValue;
}
```

As for your override bit, are you getting an error message? Or a warning? The code you've posted *seems* kosher, so it should compile. Please show the actual full message.

As for your actual parsing, I'd use `String#split("/")` to split the lineToParse into an array of tokens and then work with each token, create arguments for a Bank constructor call and create a Bank object.

i.e., code to show the concept:

```
String text = "Bank Arizona/10001/Phoenix,AZ";

String[] tokens = text.split("/");
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

Comment: I know the method is empty I don't know how to do it haha. I'm not sure if splitting it by the slashes will work but I will try, I'm not sure my teacher literally means the values are in that format. Thanks!

Comment: Also, what it shows in eclipse is a little gray circle with a gray x in it and it says exactly "Multiple markers at this line:" and then what I posted, overrides and lacks a return type

Comment: @CaptainHook: have you figured out how to make your Bank object?

Comment: I used this to try to set a Bank object and assign its attributes to what was parsed:
Bank temp = new Bank();
temp.setbankName(returnValue[0]); I assumed it works like an array
temp.setbankID(returnValue[1]);
temp.setbankAddress = //I don't know what to use for this one, because bankAddress is changed through another method in the Bank class which leads into the Address class. How do I run it through bankParser AND setBankAddress AND the setCity and setState methods? Seems like I'm overcomplicating this. Would it be easier to edit with all the related code?

Comment: @CaptainHook: show your latest attempt at this method as an edit to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use library like [Apache Common CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) for reading and writing.

```
Reader in = new StringReader("bankName/bankID/city,state");

Iterable<CSVRecord> parser = CSVFormat.newBuilder()
     .withDelimiter('/')
     .parse(in);

for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parse) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: I think that technique is a little beyond me for now, But I will definitely refer to this in the future if it comes up!

Comment: Nice, take look also at this String.format() method: `String printInfo = String.format("\nBank name:\t%s\nBank ID:\t%s\nBank address:\t%s\n", bankName, bankID, bankAddress)`

Comment: @CaptainHook: This is a nice, clean, safe way of parsing files, and you don't have to re-invent the wheel, since these folks have already done the heavy lifting for you. I've 1+'d this answer, and I suggest that you do the same.